# Rabin karp string matching algorithm complexity

Tags: string, algorithm, match

How does taking modulo in rabin algorithm helps in reducing the complexity over the native horners rule string match.Anybody please explain

Comment: define "native horners rule string match"

Comment: horner's rule is if you have a number in base x so to minimise the number of multiplications it can be written as-X(X(X(..)+.)+.)+.                       for example: 1234 can be written as 10(10(10(1)+2)+3)+4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by Horners rule you mean treating a string as a number in some base ("abcd" = 'a' * p^3 + 'b' * p^2 + 'c' * p^1 + 'd' * p^0) and comparing strings as numbers, and by Rabin algorithm you mean the essentially the same thing but modulo some other number.

The thing is using Horners rule you can only compare short strings -- otherwise you get overflow (you can use big integers to avoid it, but that is where you lose in complexity. The number corresponding to a string of length n will have O(n) digits, so arithmetic operations won't be done in O(1)).

And in Rabin-Karp algorithm the numbers corresponding to our strings will stay small since we take them modulo some other number. It may cause collisions, but if we are lucky, collisions are rare enough.

Comment: In either case we are computing the number Ist we compare it directly IInd we compare its mod so how is it reducing the complexity??

Comment: As numbers become big you can no longer compare, add and multiply it in O(1) time. Comparison and addition need O(m) operations, where m is number of  digits, complexity of multiplication can be even more, and m will be proportional to the substring length.

Comment: Say you trying to find a substring of length 50000 in a string of length 100000. What numbers will you use to represent substrings?

Comment: thanks I understood to some extent is there some website which will elaborate it further ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to read about? If you search for sites that contain structured info about algorithms, I can only name some sites in Russian (like e-maxx.ru/algo)... But if it's some particular topic, usually one can easily find some articles in English, for example, here is a tutorial on string searching algorithms: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=stringSearching (including code and explanation for Rabin-Karp algorithm)

Comment: Thankx Natalya Ginzburg I got what I was seeking

Comment: Hi @Natalya Ginzburg, how can we know BigInteger (in Java? )can avoid overflow not matter how long the string would be? Thank you in advance!